# Change window size without previewing

Tags: resize, window

In Mac if we try to resize a window it instantly changes it. But in windows/ubuntu it first shows the preview of the windows size then changes it. like

[image]

So is there any to do it like in Mac.

Comment: Yeah throw out the OS and install Ubu :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default functionality of respective operating system. You can not do anything here. You don't have have any control over the default functionality of respective operating system